# Ajax enabled webservice returns a list, how JS understand a list?

Tags: javascript, web-services, json

I was asked a question in an interview, not sure if it was a trick question or not.

Ajax enabled webservice in c# returns a list, how does javascript understand list? How will you bind it to grid?

I guess he was asking about the ArrayList as I know webservice (.asmx) method can't return List. Appreciate if someone can give an example on how can I use Javascript to populate the list into grid.

Answer (score 0):

He's probably referring to an JSON object or in this case an array.  JSON is the common language used when using AJAX.

A JSON object has the form:

```
{ fieldOne: "hello", fieldTwo:"world" }
```

A JSON Array has the form:

```
[
{ fieldOne: "hello", fieldTwo:"world" },
{ fieldOne: "hello2", fieldTwo:"world2" },
]
```

So you can see that this might well be applied to a data table/grid.

Comment: how can I bind this JSON array using Javascript? I see examples of handling JSON Array with JQuery but how to do the same using Javascript?